# Urban area mask

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to use a function like extract by mask (from arcmap or similar) in Google Earth Engine. I usually use a raster mask to class different luc. In this case is the first time that masked area not have the same size of the result raster. I just want to mask the urban area but the initial raster doesn't have an equal size from the output raster. I think that the answer is something like mask cloud pixels but I´m stuck.

```
var mascara2= classified_svm.eq(1);
var N1_2masked=classified_svm.mask(mascara2)
Map.addLayer(N1_2masked,{min:0, max:9, palette: ['#d63000']}, 'urbano1987GMZA',false);

var mascara3 = N1_2masked.eq(2)

//enmascarar (sacar) área urbana GMZA 1987
var mosaico=Mosaicos_stack.eq(mascara3);
Map.addLayer (mosaico, {bands: ['NIR_1','RED_1','GREEN_1'], min: [900,300,600], max: [4500, 2000, 1700] }, 'Mosaico20172018', false );
```